# Perl - Reformat a column in Excel

Tags: excel, perl

Using some combination of [`Win32::OLE`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32%3a%3aOLE), [`ParseExcel`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet%3a%3aParseExcel), [`WriteExcel`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet%3a%3aWriteExcel)...I want to be able to change the formatting of all of the cells in a column (or multiple columns, based on a condition) to be a custom date format, such as "yyyy-mm-dd h".

I have been able to use `Win32::OLE` to do a find and replace on an Excel file that I have open, but I am not sure the best way to reformat an entire column of cells. I imagine it will be something along the lines of parsing the file with `ParseExcel`, and using `WriteExcel` to overwrite the file after changing the format somehow.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Don't overwrite, copy to a new name (then you can compare, and the process is reversable).

You would essentially copy all the cells, modifying only the ones you need to format change.

[Excel Format Info - many examples for formatting time](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel-2.40/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel.pm#copy%28%24format%29)